# Unable to uninstall visual studio 2012 - Getting an exception thrown?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, installation, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall VS2012 to install VS2013 - But before I uninstall it from the control panel, I went ahead and removed other *seemingly* unrelated components that I never use. Mainly, I removed all the SQL-related stuff, all the ASP.NET stuff, F# runtime, Async SKD and some more stuff - I never use those. Plus everytime I uninstall VS those components remain, annoying... After I did that, and tried to uninstall VS12 Ultimate - I got an exception!

[image]

I clicked on details, and got:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   VSSetup
  P1:   vs_ultimate
  P2:   11.0.50727.01
  P3:   11.0.50727
  P4:   Uninstall
  P5:   unknown
  P6:   Crash: Exception
  P7:   5174ddfb
  P8:   2bf
  P9:   25
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I tried a lot of ways, other uninstallers (they all run the same uninstaller and thus I get the same crash) - I tried booting up the installation medium, running it from cmd with the args `/uninstall /force` - No dice...

How should I uninstall it now?

PS: Running Windows 7 X64 Ultimate

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: [MS Crosslink](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0b4b997a-fa75-49ed-a54c-4e7213bb7ed0/unable-to-uninstall-visual-studio-2012-getting-an-exception-thrown?forum=vssetup)

EDIT: Now I removed literally everything VS-related - And cleaned the registry - it's not even there in the control panel anymore - Still can't install VS2013...

EDIT: I installed VS10 - Just to see if it was really those components that I removed that are causing the problem - It didn't help.

EDIT: Someone mentioned that updating your graphics card and disabling the wpf graphics hardware acceleration might help - Since the splash screen is implemented in wpf - The settings are said to be in `HKCU/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Avalon.Graphics/DisableHWAcceleration` But I didn't find that key - I created it with no avail... - I also just updated my graphics card, no dice...

Comment: Have you tried repairing your VS2012 installation and then uninstalling it?

Comment: Via the control panel? - All I see is 'change' - when I click it I get the uninstallation issue. How can I repair it otherwise? via the install dvd/iso?

Comment: I am also unable to run the installer - it also breaks :( - I also tried `vs_ultimate.exe /repair` - same...

Comment: oh no.... omg I'm so screwed - even the VS13 installer is giving me the same issue... :(((

Comment: How far back do your system restore points go?

Comment: I don't use it - But even if I did, it restores system related stuff - and not stuff related to harddrive and storage...

Comment: Now I'm literally screwed - I tried some force uninstaller - it deleted a bunch of VS stuff and kept a lot many - Now VS12 doesn't work and I can't install/remove/repair anything :(( plzzz help!

Comment: @Andrew Please see my updates...

Comment: I replied in your MS forums thread. As your question is not about programming, SO is not really the right place for an extended discussion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for anyone who tried to help. Unfortunately I ended up formatting, as none of the solutions I tried really worked. M$, I sincerely hate you! - Lesson learned I guess, don't F with M$, it doesn't F with you.

Comment: For future reference, use the installer to remove VS first then remove any other components. If you can't do an uninstall try doing a repair or install over the top first.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it by hand

go to my computer and click on C then click on program files and find the name of the program you want to install in your case virtual basic and then delete the folder if it isn't there it will be in one of the folders in there. then delete the folder next time you try to un-install
it you will get a error just press ok and it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore your system to a earlier point of time where the visual studio was installed or if you want to install VS 2013 then update it to 2013 which was directly available from the Microsoft website and there is no need of uninstalling the VS 2012